# 個別にテーブル名を指定せず、MyISAMからInnoDBへ変更するためには？

Tags: mysql

**1データベースの中に、MyISAMテーブルとInnoDBテーブルが混在しています**
・全てInnoDBへ変更したいです
・テーブルを指定すれば変更できるのですが、数が多いため面倒です

**質門**
・指定データベースの全テーブルを(1つ1つテーブル名指定せず)InnoDBテーブルへ変更するためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
・下記みたいな感じで実行したいのですが…

```
ALTER TABLE データベース名.* ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 15.8.5 Converting Tables from MyISAM to InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html) の `User Comments` に複数のテーブルを処理するスクリプトが載っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手順１：クエリ作成
　下記のクエリを実行すると`ENGINE`が`MyISAM`のテーブルのみ抽出し、
　そのテーブルを`InnoDB`に変更するクエリが出力されます。

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_name, ' ENGINE=InnoDB;')
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND table_schema='database_name';
```

手順２：「手順１」で出力されたクエリを全て実行します。

---

クエリ1つで全てのテーブルを一括で変えたい、と言うことであれば出来ないかと思います。